# Parallel Maven executions

Tags: maven, download, parallel-processing

I'm wondering if someone has experience with parallel executions of Maven builds. I know there is a option in Jenkins to use local repository for Maven builds and I also found this issue from 2007 http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-2802 .

Is there any way to hook into Maven downloads to do basic filesystem locking? Or is it possible to completely replace it with something (what?) different?

Thank you.

I'm surprised that in year 2011 such famous tool doesn't consider possibility of parallel executions.

Answer (score 1):

On my CI server, I configure each project to have it's own local repository. Additionally I schedule a periodic job to purge these files. Why?

My reasoning is that I want to isolate each project from each other and encourage a regular "clean" build from my Nexus-based Maven repository.

Doesn't address your valid concerns, but might perhaps explain why I don't consider it much of an issue.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for reply. I think that separating local repositories will add nothing to build/project isolation since every local repository will be same.

Comment: Projects can pull dependencies from different locations. POMs can change (especially snapshot builds) resulting in different sets of transitive dependencies being pulled down. It's been my experience that a periodic "fresh" build is required to ensure that you don't get any surprises from a supposedly stable build.

Comment: Hi. Regarding different locations. It shouldn't matter from where you pull dependency because foo-1.0.0 from central should be same as foo-1.0.0 from JBoss or something is wrong. How can _changing POMs_ and _dependencies from different locations_ break isolation of builds on shared local repository?

Comment: Work with Maven long enough you'll discover a strange issue that only appears when new developer joins the team, or disappears When you delete the local repository on your build machine. I consider it a build "cache" (not a repository) and like all caches it can get stale, when compared to the data source.

Answer (score 0):

In practice this mostly matters if you are building two projects that consume artifacts the other produces (a downstream project), or produce the same artifacts (building a different configuration). In those cases, you might consider blocking the downstream build until the first is finished or pipelining the configuration builds anyway so that it can pick up the in progress build.

While the locking would be helpful to avoid errors caused by modified JAR files, locking for the context of an entire build is better done within the CI system.

There are good reasons to separate the local repositories anyway as Mark points out, and Maven could support this better by having a shared cache of releases but a per-project cache of snapshots - but for now having separate local repositories is the best way to go for that.

Comment: Hi Brett. Thanks for reply. The most likely problem is this http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-4706. Locking the entire build would result in building only one project at a time at CI (not an option). What are good reasons to separate local repository for each build? The files in ~/.me/repository will be read-only for rest of the build.

Comment: When I said locking the build, I meant in terms of builds that produce and consume each other's artifacts - not all builds. For separate local repos, I was referring to the reason that Mark gave in his answer.